# Searching Core Data entities using predicates

Tags: design-patterns, core-data, nspredicate

I am writing a Mac app that uses Core Data as its persistence layer, and am curious as to what the general consensus is with the "ownership" of searches.

Let's say that I have a class called Recipe (generated subclass of NSManagedObject) and I would like to be able to search for, say, "Recipes containing a certain ingredient", "Recipes that can feed more than 4 people", and so on.  I can conceive methods like:

```
-(NSArray *)fetchRecipesContaining:(Ingredient *)ingredient;
-(NSArray *)fetchRecipesFeedingMorePeopleThan:(int)count;
```

and the implementation knows how to construct an appropriate NSFetchRequest/NSPredicate to go get them.  The question is what object normally implements these methods?  In a Java world, these would often live in an instance method on a RecipeFactory.  I can also see the case for a class method in the Recipe class.

In a Hello World application (which most tutorials seem to offer) the logic is embedded directly in the invoking code, however, I am not that keen on having boilerplate code dealing with NSFetchRequests and NSEntityDescriptions scatted all through the invoking code.  I really would prefer to abstract that logic away and allow a more meaningful API (per above) for fetching objects.

I am inclining towards a class method on Recipe (and implemented using categories so that I don't have to modify the generated classes), but wanted to throw it out there and see what other Core Data users might use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use categories. As you note, this leaves the Xcode-generated classes untouched while allowing you to extend the functionality of the managed object class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the approach with class methods. I wasn't sure if it's good, but haven't had any trouble with it yet. Also coming to Cocoa/CoreData from Ruby on Rails with it's ActiveRecord - it seemed only logical to do so, because it's implemented the same way in ActiveRecord library as well.